# Can i prevent restarting my application each time i make a change in my java code?

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, websphere

The ide used is :IBM Rational® Software Architect™ for WebSphere® Software
Version: 7.5.5.3

The app server used is Wbesphere 6.1.

I am posting this question because my server takes about 7 to 8 minutes to start.

So even if i make a small change ,i have to wait 10 minutes to test the change in my application.So is there a way where i can make changes to my java code and test them without restarting the server.

Suggestions appreciated !!!

Note:

I am not supposed to use any build tool in my environment.

Comment: maybe disable autobuild and build manually when your changes are ready.

Comment: Am doing as you have said only till now JIV.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a plugin called [JRebel](http://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/) that let's you do changes without restarting the server.

Comment: Keppil,Thank You! But can i get any opensource version of JRebel.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have any experience with any open source alternatives. Maybe [Dynamic Code Evolution VM](http://ssw.jku.at/dcevm/) can be interesting?

Answer (score 3):

[Dynamic Code Evolution VM](http://ssw.jku.at/dcevm/) is open source alternative to JRebel you can try for reloading classes. It will do entire class redefinition, even reloads changes done to class hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically reloading classes is build into the JVM, although most implementations (specifically Oracle's) only reload (hot swap) as long as you only change code inside the body of a method.

The other problem is that in Eclipse the WTP adapter has to cooperate and only deploy the changed class definition (incremental deploy). GlassFish for some reason has always been a big opponent of incremental deployments, and hence its WTP adapter restarts the server after making even the most tiny change.

JBoss used to be a proponent of incremental deployments, but after AS 7 ("everything has to be different"), they are now a follower of the "restart the server" school as well.

Yet another issue is that plain class loading is often only one part of the story. In EJB, JSF, JPA and many other frameworks classes also have to be re-registered by the framework, caches have to be cleared, etc

This all is where something like JRebel comes it. It reloads nearly all kinds of changes to classes. It also works independently from the WTP adapter thus freeing you from the whims of the server vendors regarding if restarting is hip today and lame tomorrow or exactly the other way around. JRebel also has knowledge and plugins for many frameworks.

Unfortunately JRebel is not perfect and occasionally things will just fail, but overall it works pretty well.

One other piece of advice: most modern application servers start up in a second on relative fast hardware and with a small application or a some 10 seconds for a larger app. With those and session serialization you *almost* don't need things like JRebel anymore.

Comment: Tomcat starts in some milliseconds and still, a lot of devs use JRebel with Tomcat. Even if it supports session serialization. Why? Because the application takes a while to initialize.